# Test isContract and tx.origin in foundry

Tags: solidity

There is an solidity code:

```
modifier notContract() {
    require(!_isContract(msg.sender), "Contract not allowed");
    require(msg.sender == tx.origin, "Proxy contract not allowed");
    _;
  }
```

There is an test:

```
function testStartRound() public {
        vm.startPrank(owner);
        head_or_tail.startRound(0);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }
```

foundry test pass with error:

```bash
[10569] CounterTest::testStartRound() 
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0xd8dA6BF26964aF9D7eEd9e03E53415D37aA96045) 
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [513] HeadOrTail::startRound(0) 
    │   └─ ← "Proxy contract not allowed"
    └─ ← "Proxy contract not allowed"
```

How to pass this without errors?

I did not found any solution in foundry manuals

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with same problem. I discovered that you can override `tx.origin` and `sender` address in `foundry.toml` file. I don't know why this is not working with `vm.prank()` or `vm.startPrank()`.

**I override both these variables to assign desired address to `tx.origin` in tests.**

```
[profile.default]
src = "src"
out = "out"
libs = ["lib"]
// added lines
sender = '0x9dF0C6b0066D5317aA5b38B36850548DaCCa6B4e'
tx_origin = '0x9dF0C6b0066D5317aA5b38B36850548DaCCa6B4e'
```

There is full default foundry.toml file with default values:

https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/blob/master/crates/config/README.md#all-options

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vm.prank(address(1), address(1));`  
The first parameter is for msgSender, the second one is for txOrigin. 
Document: https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/prank

[image]